# How to get understand that the fact of serial upvoting is already found

Tags: feature-request, questions, flags, users, reputation-history

I discovered that possible *serial upvoting* takes place for some *SO* user.

But the *reputation history* has been marked `reversal   Serial upvoting reversed` (first red circled section in the image below).

How can I understand that the user's reputation was already changed (I still see the 10 *upvotes* - the second red circled section in the image below) and this reputation changes (*-90*) related to events taken place the day before (the second red circled section in the image below)?

Or maybe this *-90* change relates to some other instance of serial upvotes (maybe it were at Christmas holidays)?

[image]

Would it be better to modify *reputation history* like this:

[image]

In this case it is clear what reputation changes were rolled back.

Comment: Because the reputation history just shows the overall reputation history *by date/time*, it doesn't show reputation items and how they relate to other items. It's just the history. It shows what date/time reputation went up, what date/time reputation went down and what actions caused that change. That's the only point of that screen.

Comment: Not sure why you're confused. The upvotes were reversed, reputation "refunded". The "-60" is the net daily change. And I don't want those lines to disappear or be striked out.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I'm asking because some times ago I've post the flag in the same situation. And moderator declined my flag with note "serial upvoting was already detected and the reputation was changed"

Comment: The moderator was right. Still don't understand what is not clear for you. Might be language barrier, hopefully we'll overcome it.

Comment: @JonW I understand this mechanism is similar, but see my comment above

Comment: If you're flagging because of serial upvoting, and the reason you suspect you've been serially upvoted is because your reputation tells you about the reversal then I'm not surprised the flag is denied because the reputation repair has already taken effect. If you see serial upvoting that *doesn't* get reversed a day or so later *then* you could raise a flag but most of it gets detected automatically without you having to do anything.

Comment: Showing that information could make votes less anonymous. But it's usually obvious, anyway... like in the example.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Ok, as you can see at my post's image there are 10 records with upvotes (10 upvotes on different answers on 3 minutes interveal). It looks fishly. Next day the moderator make undo operation for 9 events of upvoting. Does it mean that I can still post the flag (for 10 upvotes)?

Comment: @JonW Ok, I got you

Comment: No moderator undid any votes. That's an automatic system.

Comment: The entry (*upvoting record*) is removed from history if it is found to be illegal? Or every fact of changing the reputation's history is permanent (immortal)?

Comment: AlexK: Once you've flagged a user like this, don't flag again, no matter what you see.

Comment: @AndrewBarber Ok, thank you

Comment: I think you just misunderstood the process. There is a daily "job" running and detecting serial voting, both serial upvoting and serial downvoting. When it find such a thing, it will automatically reverse the votes and that's what you see. No human touch there and your flag didn't cause it. Only if you detect something suspicious **and the automatic process missed it** then you can flag one of your own posts and ask a moderator to check it out.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Two simple questions: 1) If it was (in my sample) a really fact of serial upvotes (100% automatic recognition), is this automatic job already correct this situation (edit the reputation by doing the *undo* operation)? 2) How can I understand that this job corrected exactly this 10 records?

Comment: 1) Yes and 2) it didn't, it reversed only 9 upvotes (-90 reputation) meaning one upvote was "correct".

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd And how I can understand that it was changing of the records I've found (not different 9 cases, may be previous month events)? IMHO, there are no clear links between my action (make the flag) and the work of job (or manual action by moderator)

Comment: There is indeed no relation at all between your flagging and the job, and no moderation intervention whatsoever. Sorry I can't be more clear than that, hope you'll be able to understand at some point.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Thank you :)

Comment: @AndrewBarber - I disagree with the sentiment that they shouldn't ever flag again if the system reverts votes once. If there are still voting anomalies that aren't caught by the system, we might want to know about them. In this case, it turned out that there were several sock puppets that hadn't been addressed, so it was good that they flagged and let us know.

Comment: @BradLarson Good point, indeed.

Answer (score 6):

The way the page works is it keeps a *running tally* of all reputation changes.

When you gain reputation, there is a `+X` reputation event. When you lose reputation, there is a `-X` reputation event. When you go down the list and add all those events together, you get the a *total* reputation score for the user.

If we crossed out the `+X` reputation events like your second example shows, then the total reputation score would be incorrect. The only reason why the "serial upvoting reversed" event shows `-90` is because the user had previously earned `+90` from those serial upvotes. In order to "reverse" them, we have to deduct 90.

It is like a receipt at the grocery store if the clerk makes an error and rings up the same item twice, when you've only bought one. The receipt might look like this:

```
1 loaf bread        +$3.00
2 curds cheese      +$8.00
1 carton eggs       +$4.00
-credit-            -$4.00

TOTAL               +$11.00
```

Comment: Once the record appears in reputation's history it will be immortal? Only the new records appears in history, the old ones are permanent, am I right?

Comment: @AlexK Yes, that's correct.

Comment: You forgot some beverage to take this food down!